How do I remove all privileges a Snowflake role has in a database?
I am attempting to clean up a rather complicated role structure in Snowflake and implement database-level roles for access to specific objects.  If I have a role that has usage privileges on a number of schemas in a DB and select access on a number of tables in those schemas, would a REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE x FROM ROLE y be enough to "clear the board" for those privileges, or do I have to drill down further and revoke them at the schema and/or table level?

It seems from further research that the REVOKE PRIVILEGES does not cascade from the database level down, so I'll have to do explicit revocations.
